# Cypress - Alert message when running electron browser asking to update to latest Chrome fails tests covering elements

Tags: typescript, electron, cypress

I've got one test case which fails only when using Electron and the reason is that an alert appears asking me to upgrade to latest Chrome. This alert covers the elements I want to interact with.

Using Cypress version 3.4.1

If I manually dismiss such alert the test passes.[image]

I've managed to make the test to pass by using a `cy.viewport(2000,2000)` but clearly this is not a good solution.

Comment: probably the common sense solution: Did you try updating your Chrome?

Comment: I have mentioned that the problem affects Electron which is shipped with Cypress (and I've got the latest as of today 3.4.1). Furthermore on my machine Chrome is at its latest version (self-updating).